# PDO Firebird password_enc

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

I have used PDO for a long time to work with Firebird 2.5 in PHP 5.6

Today I had to connect to a new database, but I ran into the problem that it does not connect and says that it does not understand the login and password (the pair does not exist or is not correct).

I decided to try to connect via IBExpert. The result is the same, then in the additional parameters I specified `password_enc=parol` (which the previous users of the database told me) and I was able to connect to the database.

How to connect to such parameters via PDO, where to write it or it can be done through another library?

Comment: firebird version ?  PS. perhaps http://www.sql.ru/forum/interbase

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel curious thing is that the said parameter seems not described anywhere with respect to Firebird or IBExpert. I wonder if it is a db engine fork like Alvarion or Red DB

Comment: @Arioch'The `isc_dpb_password_enc` takes a Unix crypt hashed variant of the password (although `parol` doesn't look like a valid value of that hash to me). In any case, afaik, recent version of the client library will automatically transform `isc_dpb_password` to the equivalent `isc_dpb_password_enc`. It is (barely) documented in the InterBase 6.0 API Guide (pages 45, 47, 415 and 417).

Comment: Have you considered  to ask the DBA for the actual password, have them reset the password or create a separate account for you?

Comment: parol -> пароль -> parole (Fr.) stands for password in Russian. Probably here were see an demonstratively obvious substitution for the real value. Maybe he really connects in Trusted Auth mode as UNIX root => SYSDBA...

Comment: Version Firebird 2.5 In IBexpert, I specify the server address, the connection type, the port, the path to the database, login sysdba, any password (you can not specify it at all), then in the additional parameters I write password_enc=HfferOrdoR and everything works, and without this the additional parameter does not work.
A question how to fasten this parameter for PDO or interbase_connect

Comment: @Arioch'The _"obvious substitution"_, not really obvious on a site where English is the target language.

Comment: @ДмитрийИванов you perhaps would get more advices in Russian forum I linked

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know PHP, including using PDO/ibase for Firebird.

The `password_enc` property seems to be tied to the `isc_dpb_password_enc` database parameter buffer property. Its value is a (poorly) encrypted/hashed variant of the password (using the venerable UnixCrypt hash algorithm). It looks like the PHP [`ibase_connect`-command](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-connect.php) does not support this property, so you can't use it.

The only way you are going to be able to connect is to get the real (unhashed) password and use that to connect. Or you could try to find a tool to 'crack' the hash `parol` back to its original password (you may want to check with your security team if they are OK with that).

Otherwise, I suggest that you ask the DBA to either reset the password of the user, or - better - create a user specific for your application with sufficient rights (using separate users per application is a good practice anyway).

Comment: parameter password_enc strictly 11 characters

Comment: @ДмитрийИванов What do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean that a hash pair has a length of 11 characters, I need to learn how to connect with these encrypted passwords that were given to me by past administrators

Comment: @ДмитрийИванов As I specify in my answer, you can't. The ibase connection library in PHP (which is used by PDO for connecting to Firebird afaik) simply doesn't support passing that value. You'll need the unhashed password.